# What is interpreter-aware SparkContext

Tags: apache-spark

In the spark docs, there is mentioned a line

> In the Spark shell, a special interpreter-aware SparkContext is already created for you, in the variable called sc.

reference : https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html

What does **interpreter-aware SparkContext** means here ?

Answer (score 1):

You can run the spark-shell with python or scala. The spark context knows which one. As it is interactive there is an interpreter. It's a common computing concept, that is all.